# undefined reference error for all methods of Base class

Tags: c++

I have following base class and derived class structure.

base/include/Base.h

```
namespace A
{
namespace B
{

class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    Base(const Type type, const Name name);
    virtual ~Base();

    // Copy constructor
    Base(const Base& other);

    // Assignment operator
    Base& operator= (const Base& rhs);

    // Comparison
    bool operator< (const Base& rhs);

    std::string toString();

    //These enums have been defined in same file above the class

    enum Type mType;
    enum Name mName;
};

}
}
```

base/src/Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"
//and other required includes

namespace A
{
namespace B
 {

Base::Base()
{

}

Base::Base(const Type type, const Name name)
{

}

Base::~Base()
{

}

// Copy constructor
Base::Base(const Base& other)
{

}

// Assignment operator
Base& Base::operator= (const Base& rhs)
{

}

// Comparison
bool Base::operator< (const Base& rhs)
{

}

std::string Base::toString()
{

}
 }
}
```

base/test/test.h

```
 #include "Base.h"
  namespace A
  {
   namespace B
    {
   class Derived: public Base
   {

       public:
    Derived();
    Derived(const Type type, const Name name);
    virtual ~Derived();

    Derived(const Derived& other);
    Derived& operator= (const Derived& rhs);

    virtual std::string toString();
};

  }
  }
```

base/test/test.cpp

```
   #include "test.h"
   namespace A
   {
    namespace B
     {


    Derived::Derived()
    {

    }

    Derived::Derived(const Type type, const Name name)
    :Base(type, name)
    {

    }

    Derived::~Derived()
    {

    }

    Derived::Derived(const Derived& other)
    {

    }

    Derived& Derived::operator= (const Derived& rhs)
    {

    }

    std::string Derived::toString()
    {

    }
};

    }
 }
```

Now, I am building libBase.a for Base class directory.
And then I am trying to compile Derived class on command line like this in base/test directory:

```
 g++ *.cpp -o Test  \
  -I /cygdrive/c/projects/base/include \
  -L /cygdrive/c/projects/base/Build -lBase
```

But I get errors like:

```
/tmp/ccjLwXZp.o:Derived.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `A::B::Base::Base()
/tmp/ccjLwXZp.o:Derived.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `A::B::Base::Base()
/tmp/ccjLwXZp.o:Derived.cpp:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `A::B::base::Base(const Type type, const Name name)'
```

These errors I get for all the functions defined in base class.
  I am not sure, what is it that I am doing wrong.
  I have checked that libBase.a is in proper place

Comment: How do you build the `Base` shared object?

Comment: Its a Visual Studio project which has got few more files and generates .a

Comment: Well, it seems you are not linking to that `.a`.

Comment: Thats what I thought. But I have checked: I am doing -L /cygdrive/c/projects/base/Build -lBase and libBase.a is in required directory

Comment: You mention `Base` being in a Visual Studio project. Where is the .a file coming from? Reason I ask is if everything is being built properly it may be a name mangling issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the fact you've declared `Type` and `Name` enums after the c-tor declaration. Due to this the compiler can't build the `Base` class.

```
class Base
{
public:
    enum Type mType;   // <-- define the type and Name here, before
    enum Name mName;   // <-- the C-tor (actual usage)


    Base();
    Base(const Type type, const Name name);
    virtual ~Base();

    // Copy constructor
    Base(const Base& other);

    // Assignment operator
    Base& operator= (const Base& rhs);

    // Comparison
    bool operator< (const Base& rhs);

    std::string toString();

    //These enums have been defined in same file above the class

    //enum Type mType;   // <<- your original location
    //enum Name mName;
};
```